# How to send/post message to window's form from subclassed button class

Tags: c#, winforms

In my form I have 2 buttons and one button is using subclassed button class.

This class has overridden `WndProc` and catching `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. when receiving `WM_MOUSEMOVE` I have to invoke form's `button1_mousemove`.

How to achieve it?

```cs
public class myownbutton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    private int  WM_MOUSEMOVE                   = 0x0200;
    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
        { 
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}

partial class Form1
{
    private myownbutton button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
}


private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method call from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237397/method-call-from-another-form)

Comment: The Button class already works this way, its WndProc() method calls OnMouseMove().  Which raises the MouseMove event.  If you want to customize that behavior then you override OnMouseMove.